# Not able to see image after adding display flex. Image got shrunken

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am creating a page in React  which left side of page contains image with Carousel and right side has its information.
Before display:flex the images are visible but after adding display:flex to place image in left side but the image got shrunken and dots of Carousel is visible like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQjbI.png)

Also Carousel circle should be below image not center of the screen

Product.jsx:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const {id}=useParams();
  const dispatch=useDispatch()  ; 
  const {product,loading,error}=useSelector((state)=>state.productDetails);
  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
  },[dispatch,id])
  return (
    <Fragment>
          <div className="ProductDetails">
            <div>
              <Carousel>
                {product.image &&
                  product.image.map((item, i) => (
                    <img
                      className="CarouselImage"
                      key={item.url}
                      src={item.url}
                      alt={`${i} Slide`}
                    />
                  ))}
               </Carousel>
            </div>
          </div>

    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default ProductDetails;
```

css is:

```
.ProductDetails{
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 6vmax;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling flexbox via `display:flex` applies some defaults for `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow`, and `flex-basis`.

At the moment, the only elements in your component with explicitly defined widths are the `ProductDetails` container (set to `100vw`) div and carousel circle buttons (set to `1em` each through the `react-material-ui-carousel` package). The flexbox defaults dictate that the ideal size of a container is defined by its contents  and although the images are certainly wider, they end up effectively inheriting the width from the carousel buttons, which results in the images getting smaller.

To overcome this you can do a few things:

- set all the child elements to fill up all the space of their parents

```
.ProductDetails div {
   width: 100%;
}
```

- tell flexbox that child elements should fill up the space of their
  parents

```
.ProductDetails div {
   flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

- tell flexbox that child elements should expand

```
.ProductDetails div {
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See more information [here](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/)

Comment: Still not working

Comment: It's possible you've got some other CSS that's taking priority, I would definitely recommend checking out what CSS the individual elements are actually inheriting via the browser's Inspect Element. Here's a quick example of how I got it working on my end: https://playcode.io/1534710 (note that the height is initially not correct, it fixes itself when the carousel rotates, most likely this is just because of how the document is embedded in this environment, but if you have no issues with height, then you can ignore)

Comment: the image is visible now thansks but the Carousel dots are in middle of the screen . How can I achieve Carousel dots position below the image and at the middle of half of width of image?

Comment: It'll be hard for me help you debug this without seeing more of the existing code. Are you able to share the minimum code that is causing this issue? Most likely you need to fiddle with the height property (or other similar styling) on one of the carousel elements.